# CAShapeLayer get current scale

Tags: swift, xcode, transform, calayer, cashapelayer

I have a `CAShapeLayer` that scales to an unknown scale number:

```
myCAShapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(newScale, newScale, 1)
```

Then at a certain point, I have to run a `CABasicAnimation` from current scale back to 1:

```
let animation1 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
animation1.fromValue = myCAShapeLayer.value(forKeyPath: "transform.scale") as! CGFloat
animation1.toValue = 1.0
animation1.duration = 0.5
myCAShapeLayer.add(animation1, forKey: nil)
```

when I log `myCAShapeLayer.value(forKeyPath: "transform.scale") as! CGFloat` after each `CATransform3DMakeScale`, its always 1.0, though visually the layer is scaled up.

I also tried `myCAShapeLayer.presentation()?.value(forKeyPath: "transform.scale") as! CGFloat` and its also 1.0

Comment: what is the value of your newScale? the problem is probably there. please post your other code. thanks.

Comment: newScale varies from 1.5 to 2.0.  Visually it seems to scale properly also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we go to the declaration of `CATransform3DMakeScale`. We have this information

```
/* Returns a transform that scales by `(sx, sy, sz)':
 * t' = [sx 0 0 0; 0 sy 0 0; 0 0 sz 0; 0 0 0 1]. */
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func CATransform3DMakeScale(_ sx: CGFloat, _ sy: CGFloat, _ sz: CGFloat) -> CATransform3D
```

So, as we know what `indices` in matrix are changed for this `transform`, we can get each as below,

```
shape.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(2.09, 4.88, 3.49)
print(shape.transform.m11)
print(shape.transform.m22)
print(shape.transform.m33)
```

Output:

```
2.09
4.88
3.49
```

Comment: This seem to work for me, at least in this particular instance.  Thank you!